# javaプログラムで動画を画像データに分けたい

Tags: java, opencv

#### 行いたいこと

javaを用いて動画データ(.MOV)を画像ファイルに分けたいです．
IDEはEclipseを使っています．

お願いします．

Comment: `ffmpeg` 辺りのユーティリティを使えば簡単に静止画を抜き出せそうですが、質問としてはあくまで Java のプログラムでなんとかしたい、という事でしょうか。 / 余談として、Eclipse は「統合開発環境 (IDE)」なので、「プラットフォーム」と呼ぶのは違和感があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます，
そうですねjavaを用いて動画を入力し，画像を出力したいです．
修正ありがとうございます，以後気を付けます．

Comment: 質問(およびタイトル)は後からでも [編集] できますので、より具体的な説明がしてあると回答も付きやすくなると思います。必要に応じて見直してみてください。

Comment: 結局`ffmpeg`を使っているようですが、こんな記事があります。[JavaCVを使って動画ファイルから静止画ファイルを生成する方法](http://www.ria-lab.com/archives/1164), [Grab each frame from video and save as jpg in internal sd #620](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/620), [Introducing JavaCV frame converters](http://bytedeco.org/news/2015/04/04/javacv-frame-converters/), [How can I get a frame sample (jpeg) from a video (mov)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15735716/9014308)

Comment: 何から何までありがとうございます．勉強してみます．